# XML parsing using NSXMLParser in iphone?

Tags: iphone, xcode4, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I am parsing `XML` response.But I am not getting desired result.Could not understand where Im going wrong?
My XML response looks like this :

```
<List>   
    <User>
         <Id>1</Id>
    </User>
    <User>
      <Employee>
          <Name>John</Name>
          <TypeId>0</TypeId>
          <Id>0</Id>
      </Employee> 
         <Id>0</Id>
     </User>
</List>
```

From this I want the values of Id(1) and Name(John).I dont want Id(0)

My Parsing code is :

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{

    if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"List"]) 
    {
        arr=[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        drr=[[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init]; 

    }
   srr=[[NSMutableString alloc] init];
   } 


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{


    [srr appendString:string];
}
-(void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName{

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Id"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Id"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
        return;
    }    

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"Name"])
    {

        [drr setObject:srr forKey:@"Name"];
        [srr release],srr=nil;
        [arr addObject:drr]; 

        return;
    } 

    if([elementName isEqualToString:@"List"])
    {
       [drr release];

     }

    [srr release],srr=nil;

   }
```

I want output to be :

```
(
{
Name="John";
Id="1";
}
)
```

But Im getting like this:

```
(
        {
        Name = John;
        Id = "0";
    },
        {
        Name = John;
        Id = "0";
    }
)
```

How can I do it?

Comment: use this link [xml parsing example][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13117711/unable-to-store-and-retrieve-xml-data-from-nsmutablearray/13119018#13119018

Comment: The XML listed in your example is extremely odd. Based on the formatting it looks like there are 2 users (id 0 and id 1), and that user 0 has/is an employee named John whose id is also 0, and is of type id 0. This is made even more strange by the fact that you want "Name=John:Id=1" as a result. I can understand that in many circumstances you cannot post your real XML data, but something closer to real would certainly help us help you.

Comment: But Im getting this response from service url and I have to do it as it is ..I cannot change the service.Please help..

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to use [TBXML](http://tbxml.co.uk/TBXML/TBXML_Free.html) instead of NSXMLParser. It's much faster and easier to use.